# Please help identify this conncetor

Tags: connector

[image: Round connector]

[image][image]

I am trying to mate this connection.

It is a 5 pin round connector that has two keys at 90 degree apart. The outside uses a threaded retaining ring.

Having a heck of a time finding anything on this and I hope someone here can help.

Thanks!

Ken

Comment: At least put a ruler beside it to give us some idea of scale.

Comment: Sorry. I was going to do that originally. Dimensional photos added.

Answer (score 0):

I think (but I'm not a professional) it is a GX16 aviation connector, see:

[link](https://www.moddiy.com/products/Aviation-Plug-GX16-3%252dPin%7B47%7D4%252dPin%7B47%7D5%252dPin%7B47%7D6%252dPin-Male-%26-Female-Wire-Panel-Chassis-Connector.html)

They come in different kinds of number of pins.